# Does big-Oh impose an ordered partition on the set of the "usual" functions?

Tags: reference-request, big-o-notation

The example in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2101185/165144) proves the fact familiar to CS students - that the "big-O" is not a total order. However, most algorithm running times analyzed using big-Oh notation are not expressed in piecewise form like this example. In fact, most algorithms I am familiar with have a running time expressed in terms of polynomials, exponentiations and logs.

Consider the recursively defined class of functions which includes $f(n) = c$ for any constant $c$, $f(n) = n$, and any functions of the form $f + g, f \cdot g, \log(f), \exp(f)$ where $f,g$ are in the class. Does $O$ impose an ordered partition on this class of functions? The functions with the same big-$O$ growth is in the same part.

Here are my thoughts:

Note that specifying $f \cdot g$ is actually redundant, since $f \cdot g = \exp(\log(f) + \log(g))$. Since the functions are inductively defined, perhaps there is an inductive proof.

Comment: $2n = O(n)$ but also $n=O(2n)$...

Comment: @nir Yeah, you need to replace "total ordering" with "[weak ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering)" for this question to make sense.  Here's a [Scott Aaronson proof](https://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=263#comment-7283) of a related theorem on O notation classes. I think I might have seen more about this from him somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was shown by Hardy in his monograph [Orders of Infinity](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/38079/38079-pdf.pdf).